# Different thread handling for Flux.fromIterable as a controller method result

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

**My environment:**

Spring Boot `2.0.1.RELEASE` with webflux running on Servlet container over Tomcat. I have defined one controller with code below.

```
package com.demo.controller;

import com.demo.service.pojo.User;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/reactive")
public class ReactiveInfoController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReactiveInfoController.class);

    private final List<User> users;

    public ReactiveInfoController() {
        final User user1 = new User();
        user1.setName("AN");
        user1.setSurname("AS");

        final User user2 = new User();
        user2.setName("BN");
        user2.setSurname("BS");

        final User user3 = new User();
        user3.setName("CN");
        user3.setSurname("CS");

        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);
        users.add(user3);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/list/a")
    public Flux<User> listUsersA() {
        final Iterable<User> userIterable = new Iterable<User>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<User> iterator() {
                final Iterator<User> iterator = users.iterator();
                return new Iterator<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return iterator.hasNext();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public User next() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            logger.error("Error while sleeping.", e);
                        }
                        return iterator.next();
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public void forEach(final Consumer<? super User> action) {
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<User> spliterator() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        return Flux.fromIterable(userIterable).doOnNext(user -> {
            logger.info("[ZZZ] received: " + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
        });
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/list/b")
    public Flux<User> listUsersB() {
        final Iterable<User> userIterable = new Iterable<User>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<User> iterator() {
                final Iterator<User> iterator = users.iterator();
                return new Iterator<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            logger.error("Error while sleeping.", e);
                        }
                        return iterator.hasNext();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public User next() {
                        return iterator.next();
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public void forEach(final Consumer<? super User> action) {
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<User> spliterator() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        return Flux.fromIterable(userIterable).doOnNext(user -> {
            logger.info("[ZZZ] received: " + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname());
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see the only difference between endpoints is `Thread.sleep()` call. In `A` system is waiting while getting value, while in `B` system is waiting for information if any more value will be available. This methods shows two possible scenarios:

A. System know how many items will be sent or know that more will come. So iterator `hasNext()` return true immediately. Then system blocks for one second on method `next()` while waiting for next item to be sent.

B. System doesn't know how many items will be send or that more will come. It will know that it has more data when they come or information that no more elements will be sent was delivered. So it blocks on `hasNext()` method. Method `next()` returns value immediately as it was received during calling `hasNext()` method.

**Problem**

1. Calling endpoint `/demo/reactive/user/list/a`

command:

```
curl -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' http://localhost:8001/demo/reactive/user/list/a
```

result:

```
data:{"name":"AN","surname":"AS"}
data:{"name":"BN","surname":"BS"}
data:{"name":"CN","surname":"CS"}
```

logs:

```
2018-05-10 12:17:00,965 INFO  [com.demo.controller.ReactiveInfoController] (http-nio-20012-exec-5) [ZZZ] received: AN AS
2018-05-10 12:17:01,967 INFO  [com.demo.controller.ReactiveInfoController] (MvcAsync8) [ZZZ] received: BN BS
2018-05-10 12:17:02,971 INFO  [com.demo.controller.ReactiveInfoController] (MvcAsync9) [ZZZ] received: CN CS
```

As expected after 1s first line shows, after next 1s second line shows and after next 1s third line shows. From logs you can see that users were received one by one in 1s interval. Moreover they were processed by different threads.

2. Calling endpoint `/demo/reactive/user/list/b`

command:

```
curl -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' http://localhost:8001/demo/reactive/user/list/b
```

result:

```
data:{"name":"AN","surname":"AS"}
data:{"name":"BN","surname":"BS"}
data:{"name":"CN","surname":"CS"}
```

logs:

```
2018-05-10 12:20:12,321 INFO  [com.demo.controller.ReactiveInfoController] (http-nio-20012-exec-6) [ZZZ] received: AN AS
2018-05-10 12:20:13,321 INFO  [com.demo.controller.ReactiveInfoController] (http-nio-20012-exec-6) [ZZZ] received: BN BS
2018-05-10 12:20:14,322 INFO  [com.demo.controller.ReactiveInfoController] (http-nio-20012-exec-6) [ZZZ] received: CN CS
```

As not expected after 3s all lines show up same time. No streaming. But from logs you can see that users were received one by one in 1s interval. And also they were processed by only one thread.

**Question**

Is it normal behaviour or is it a bug? I don't know if I am missing some required knowledge or if these two requests should behave the same (both should stream result as they are ready).

**EDIT 1**

I'll try to better show what is happening with timeline.

A.

```
+ command execution start: curl -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' http://localhost:8001/demo/reactive/user/list/a
| [1s]
+ output shows: data:{"name":"AN","surname":"AS"}
| [1s]
+ output shows: data:{"name":"BN","surname":"BS"}
| [1s]
+ output shows: data:{"name":"CN","surname":"CS"}
+ command execution stop
```

B.

```
+ command execution start: curl -H 'Accept: text/event-stream' http://localhost:8001/demo/reactive/user/list/a
| [1s]
| [1s]
| [1s]
+ output shows: data:{"name":"AN","surname":"AS"}
+ output shows: data:{"name":"BN","surname":"BS"}
+ output shows: data:{"name":"CN","surname":"CS"}
+ command execution stop
```

I hope it shows the difference.

Comment: The lines show up at the same time, but the times are 1s apart. The behaviour appears to be the same (as far as timing is concerned) from where I'm reading this. Internal difference appears to be in multithreaded processing, which could be explained by the way that `Flux.fromIterable()` executes. You'd have to dive into its internals for that.

Comment: Hi, I added some more explanaition of situation. The behaviour is not the same and I just want to know why.